# Changing default look of materialize scrollspy function

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I am using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/scrollspy.html) framework for my website. I am using a scrollspy function for the navigation bar. But I want to change the default color of red to white and change from vertical line to a horizontal line underneath nav links.

**Now I have this**

[image: scrollspy]

**What I want is**

[image: desired image]

JS code for scrollspy function.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();
      });
```

I don't know which specific classes to change.

Comment: @Hunter Turner Thanks man. I was trying ways to clip the blank part.

Comment: No worries bro, I'm 1 step closer to my "Strunk & White" badge thanks to you, haha. :)

Comment: Hahahaha You the man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a side table of contents on your website, you can change the css for the table-of-contents class.

Go to the materialize.css file, and find the following code:

```
  .table-of-contents a.active {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border-left: 2px solid #ea4a4f;
  }
```

Then you can replace it with this:

```
  .table-of-contents a.active {
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  }
```

To see the results, you have to link the materialize.css file instead of materialize.min.css in your html. In a production environment, you will need to minimize the modified materialize.css file.

Maybe it's a little late, but I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

of-content class, you can add css like this

```
nav ul li a.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
```

means, when element **a** is active, it will give border-bottom